# Implementing Search bar in Android

Tags: android, search

I am developing an app for samsung galaxy S2, version 2.3.3. I want to implement search bar on it. Can anyone help me about this. I tried android developers guide but all in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a searchable.xml like :

```
     <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:label="@string/search_label"
   android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
   android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
   android:searchSuggestAuthority="dictionary"
   android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW">
</searchable>
```

You must refer to the following link.It will help you.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html

Comment: Thanks ekjyot and +1 for help

Comment: i will make xml named searchable in drawable and my ques is how to call that in main xml

Comment: when i made a folder named xml and put searchable in it , on compiling it shows new xml in same folder named searchable_out and its empty and then it gives error in log .Can you tell me how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need (1) a searchable.xml like ekjyot just suggested and (2) a content provider.  It's a pretty good sized project so hopefully you have a bit of Android experience already.  One AWESOME resource is this article on the Android developer's site: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html. Good luck and come back if you have specific questions!

Comment: how to use content provider??

Comment: and how to include searchable in main xml?